# Unity GridLayoutGroup dynamicaly created cells size problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container, unity-ui

I want to populate GridLayoutGroup  child's dynamical from Prefab.
Here is my GridLayoutGroup settings

[image]

Here is code for my dynamical  creating cells

```
        for (int i = 0; i < formSkins.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject skinElement = Instantiate(prifabSkinElemet, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
            skinElement.transform.SetParent(skinElementParent.transform);
        }
```

And here is what I get as a result:

[image]

But when I add Prefab component (cells) by drag and drop in to the GridLayutGroup element I get what I wanted and that I'm expect to be.

[image]

Can some one tell me why when dynamicaly creating child's size not match as when I drag and drop ?

Thanks

Comment: SetParent(x, false)

Comment: @Iggy Thanks, write this as answer I will accepted as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transform.SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

```
public void SetParent(Transform parent, bool worldPositionStays);
```

> **worldPositionStays:** If true, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified
>   such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and
>   scale as before.

So using `transform.SetParent(x, false)` will reset its position, scale, and rotation.